# Combining json register results in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have searched for an answer to the following question. I could find some related answers but unfortunatly doesn't solve my issue.

i have this json out put from debugging a register in a win_find task:

```
    - name: find docs older than 15 days
        win_find:
          paths: '{{ main_dir }}\{{ item }}\docs'
          age: 15d
        loop: '{{ all_folders}}'
        register: register_files

    - debug:
        var: register_files
```

this is the debug output (i have removed some attributes to make the code shorter and easier to explain):

```
    "register_files": {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_item_label": "folder_1", 
            "changed": false, 
            "examined": 378, 
            "files": [
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "0351d8fffad7a16a5c21136ac5a77b33931237ad", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633779.2339206, 
                }, 
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "d25dd0915fe825790c8c3a27acdf6f5b34f6686b", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633767.7103796, 
            "item": folder_1", 
            "matched": 302
        }, 
            "_ansible_item_label": "folder_2", 
            "changed": false, 
            "examined": 266, 
            "files": [
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "0351d8fffad7a16a5c21136ac5a77b33931237ad", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633779.2339206, 
                }, 
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "d25dd0915fe825790c8c3a27acdf6f5b34f6686b", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633767.7103796, 
            "item": folder_2", 
            "matched": 125
```

Because the code lookup two different folders i am getting the results back as two different dict lists. how can i combine those into one so i can get those results:

```
            "files": [
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "0351d8fffad7a16a5c21136ac5a77b33931237ad", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633779.2339206, 
                }, 
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "d25dd0915fe825790c8c3a27acdf6f5b34f6686b", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633767.7103796, 
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "0351d8fffad7a16a5c21136ac5a77b33931237ad", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633779.2339206, 
                }, 
                {
                    "attributes": "Archive", 
                    "checksum": "d25dd0915fe825790c8c3a27acdf6f5b34f6686b", 
                    "creationtime": 1568633767.7103796,
```

Comment: You did not simply remove some attributes from your debug. Your json is malformed. I corrected it

Comment: @Zeitounator rolled back your changes. Your are assuming a wrong copy paste here but could possibly be the issue of the OP in the first place. When fixing code in question, please first ensure it indeed **is** just typo

Comment: I am not getting any errors, I just need some advise how to achieve my goal to combine two dicts from json output. So what i have posted is to give you guys an idea about what i am trying to do

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε The OP has itself said in his question that he removed attributes for clarity and simply did not close his example json correctly which prevents a responder from copying/pasting the example to make tests to answer. So I definitely think I was right but nevermind.

Comment: @Marvelous is your question really as trivial as that? That you should maybe review your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to ask this and this only. Simplifying it would make it a really great question.

Comment: @Zeitounator let's agree to not agree on this :) An edit on the JSON could hide a comprehension issue hidden in a question that would have come from the malformated JSON in the first place, preventing other to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
my_files: "{{ register_files.results|json_query('[].files')|flatten }}"
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to get the result you want is to use the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) with the correct [`jmespath`](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) expression

```
    - name: Get file info
      debug:
        msg: "{{ register_files | json_query('results[].files[]') | list }}"
```

This was tested against the following data structure taken from your example and fixed to end up with a correct json.

```
    "register_files": {
      "changed": false,
      "msg": "All items completed",
      "results": [
        {
          "_ansible_item_label": "folder_1",
          "changed": false,
          "examined": 378,
          "files": [
            {
              "attributes": "Archive",
              "checksum": "0351d8fffad7a16a5c21136ac5a77b33931237ad",
              "creationtime": 1568633779.2339206
            },
            {
              "attributes": "Archive",
              "checksum": "d25dd0915fe825790c8c3a27acdf6f5b34f6686b",
              "creationtime": 1568633767.7103796
            }
          ],
          "item": folder_1",
          "matched": 302
        },
        {
          "_ansible_item_label": "folder_2",
          "changed": false,
          "examined": 266,
          "files": [
            {
              "attributes": "Archive",
              "checksum": "0351d8fffad7a16a5c21136ac5a77b33931237ad",
              "creationtime": 1568633779.2339206
            },
            {
              "attributes": "Archive",
              "checksum": "d25dd0915fe825790c8c3a27acdf6f5b34f6686b",
              "creationtime": 1568633767.7103796
            }
          ],
          "item": folder_2",
          "matched": 125
        }
      ]
    }
```

Please make sure you check your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your future questions.

Comment: Thnaks. both, your solution and also Vladimir's solution work! Amazing to see that there are different apprroaches. Thanks again for help.